# Get output of the last 4 layers of BERT (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, tpu, tensorflow-hub

I was going through Andreas Poyiatzis' article posted on towardsdatascience.com. Below is the link for the article.

https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-extract-contextualized-word-embeddings-from-bert-keras-tf-67ef29f60a7b#--responses

The embeddings generated are through the use of TPU. But I want to run it on my local machine, which does not support TPU. Can someone let me know how can I run the same code on the CPU? Your help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the link, the code says if no TPU is available, Estimator falls back to CPU or GPU. Just make sure you set `use_tpu = False` everywhere it shows up:

```
  # If TPU is not available, this will fall back to normal Estimator on CPU
  # or GPU.
  estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
      use_tpu=False,
      model_fn=model_fn,
      config=run_config,
      predict_batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      train_batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Also directly above that in the `model_fn_builder` call. Like this:

```
model_fn = model_fn_builder(
      bert_config=bert_config,
      init_checkpoint=INIT_CHECKPOINT,
      layer_indexes=layer_indexes,
      use_tpu=False,
      use_one_hot_embeddings=True)
```